# Is there an way to add reference(dll) in parent path in C#?

Tags: c#, json.net, mono, command-line-interface, csc

== compile command ==

```
csc -r:"../Newtonsoft.Json.dll" test.cs
```

== exec command ==

```
mono test.exe
```

== exec result : dependency error ==

```
 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies.
```

"Newtonsoft.Json.dll" this file is located in parent path. so I added a reference about dll and compile succeeded, but when I executed the exe file, it failed to get dll reference I added.

And when I put cs file and dll file together in the same directory, it worked very well, but that's not what I wanted.

Is there a solution to add a reference from dll file which is located in parent path using command line interface?

I used csc for compiler and mono for execution.

Thanks.

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` must be directly or indirectly referred by `.exe` project, if you running `.exe` separately  then this dll must be in the same directory folder

Comment: @ashwathmabiyan That's not exactly true. The file can be in a couple of locations to be picked up correctly, more with the right application configuration and anywhere at all with a little code.

Comment: @Corey right agree, but as you mentioned it needs extra configuration at project properties level. In my above comment I had mentioned considering a general/common case.

Comment: @ashwathmabiyan Your original comment said nothing about qualifiers, it said that there was no way to do what the question asks. You added the "general/common case" after the fact. When you put things that way you're not just wrong, you're telling people that they shouldn't look for solutions to the problem. Please stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

References are pathless. What that means is that wherever the assembly resides, all your program knows is that it has a reference to `Newtonsoft.Json, Version=x.x.x.x, Culture=...` and so on. You can do some things with the application configuration (`application.config` or `myprogram.exe.config`) to organize things into subfolders (using the [`probing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element) setting) or specify a URL location for the file (using the [`codebase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/codebase-element) setting). You can set up the environment to change the search path and so on.

Or you can add some runtime code that allows you to override the default behavior and the call [`Assembly.LoadFrom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom) to provide a full path to the file. You can either do it as part of your initialization or in a handler for the [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve) event - which is generally better method since it will only be called when the assembly is actually needed.

For example:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

static class ParentPathResolver
{
    public static void Init()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(Resolve);
    }

    private static Assembly? Resolve(object? sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        var filename = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
        var fullname = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine("..", filename));
        if (File.Exists(fullname))
            return Assembly.LoadFrom(fullname);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Of course you can add your own code to the `Resolve` method to search pretty much anywhere, just as long as you don't get caught in a resolution loop. I've used the `AssemblyResolve` event to do fun things like loading assemblies from compressed resources.